# consulta fecha en jdatechooser java

Tags: java, mysql

tengo una tabla de ventas de productos que también registra la fecha de venta. He estado haciendo diversas consultas, pero en una de ellas tengo un problema. Quiero hacer una consulta de una fecha determinada, la fecha que indique jdatechooser. Cómo formulo la consulta?... Cómo obtengo la fecha del jdatechooser?.. espero me puedan apoyar.

[image: lista ventas]
[image: consulta ventas]

Answer (score 1):

Lo que vas a hacer, será parsear las fechas debido a que estas tienen otro formato
en mi caso coloqué en la primer linea de código dentro de la clase del botón donde está la consulta:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

y ya dentro de la consulta parseamos de nuevo la fecha para que nos salga con el formato que queremos:

```
SSQL= "SELECT * FROM Agregar WHERE Format(Fecha, 'dd/mm/yyyy')= Format('"+formatter.format(FechaUs)+"', 'dd/mm/yyyy')";
```

si necesitas mas ayuda me puedes mandar un correo a:

> amilkarenriquez@gmail.com
>
> thestarwookie@gmail.com

espero te sirva :D